# Can I auto generate js script for automation in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, testing, instruments

I want to automate UI testing for an iOS app. Is it possible to generate JS script via the Xcode instrument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes . it is possible.

1. First you have to got to product -> Profile and select the Automation.
2. In Automation window , Click on Add  and create script.
3. Now press recored button which is available in bottom of the window.
4. Now simply you have to navigate through you app when it lunch.In script window script would be generated according to your interaction with application.
5. after finish, click on stop button and now you can see the UIAutomation of you app by clicking record button or play button.